# Fetching querystring parameters from returnurl in Controller action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string, querystringparameter, returnurl

I am new to mvc. I have a returnurl argument in my action method of my controller sent from another controller.
The returnurl has querystring parameters which i require to process in my controller action method.

I tried `Request.QueryString[]` but the url is encoded so unable to fetch the parameters.

Is there a way to fetch the parameters and its values from the returnurl argument?

Comment: You can get by `Index`. `Request.QueryString[0]`

Answer (score 0):

get your returnurl from querystring which you said was encoded.

Decode it using the built in HttpUtility.

```
string returnUrlEncoded = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];
string returnUrlDecoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(returnUrlEncoded);
```

Then use the advice / example code in [extract query string from a URL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082664/extract-query-string-from-a-url-string)

to get your querystring values from your return url.