# Regex to catch links with special codes

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that is close but not quite there:

```
(https?)://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,\<\>]*)
```

It's supposed to catch links with special codes in them before they get replaced.  Here's an example text:

```
some leading text <a>http://subsite.domain.com/somepage.aspx?querystring1=<#specialcode#></a>. Some text afterwards
```

Another example:

```
some leading text <a>http://subsite.domain.com/somepage.aspx?querystring1=<#first#>&querystring2=<#another#>&querystring3=foo&querystring4=<#bar#></a>
```

Or even just "plain" links:

```
some leading text <a>http://subsite.domain.com/somepage.aspx?querystring1=foo&querystring2=bar</a>
```

I want to capture all these links, without the tags, and some links contain the delimiters.

According to the tester, it's close, but it keeps catching the closing a tag at the end AND the period.  I get why, I just don't know how to fix it.  In my example, I need to catch the <#specialcode#> and any number of other query strings after it.  Without too many details, the <# and #> are delimiters in an application.  Any help here would be appreciated.

I took the root regex from here: [Get url from a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125016/get-url-from-a-text)
I've tried testing it here: http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: bruh... regex for this? Use `ParseQueryString` http://stackoverflow.com/a/6082703/940217

Comment: @KyleFalconer How does that find and extract a link from  mass of text?

Comment: Would be so much easier if your text is HTML...

Comment: I take it that you are not actually using `#` unencoded in the parameters - it is a reserved character: [Characters allowed in GET parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1455639/1115360).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Waiting for the [pony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), I guess :)

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, they get replaced by the app, which I tried to clarify in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input text isn't a proper HTML document, and assuming you're just looking to extract the url and query strings and parameters, this regex will do it:

```
(https?:\/\/[^?<]+)[?]?(([^=<]+)=(<#[^&<]*#>|[^&<]*)&?)*
```

This is based on the following test inputs:

```
some leading text <a>http://subsite.domain.com/somepage.aspx?querystring1=<#specialcode#></a>. Some text afterwards
some leading text <a>http://subsite.domain.com/somepage.aspx?querystring1=<#specialcode#>&querystring2=foo</a>. Some text afterwards
some leading text <a>http://subsite.domain.com/somepage.aspx?querystring1=<#specialcode#>&querystring2=foo&querystring3=<#specialcode2#></a>. Some text afterwards
some leading text <a>http://subsite.domain.com/somepage.aspx</a>. Some text afterwards
```

The results would be in the capturing groups.

If the given text were an HTML document, then the regex would have to change, because instead of the link being inside `<a>http://linkhere.com</a>`, it would be in the `href` attribute: `<a href="http://linkhere.com">link here</a>`